# Mongo query using aggregation for dates

Tags: mongodb, date, isodate

In the following query I'm trying to find entries in my `articles` collection made in the last week, sorted by the number of votes on that article. The `$match` doesn't seem to work(maybe I dont know how to use it). The following query works perfectly, so its not a date format issue,

```
db.articles.find(timestamp:{
                '$lte':new Date(),
                '$gte':new Date(ISODate().getTime()-7*1000*86400)}
        })
```

But this one doesn't fetch any results. Without the `$match` it also fetches the required results(articles sorted by votecount).

```
db.articles.aggregate([
    {
        $project:{
            _id:1,
            numVotes:{$subtract:[{$size:"$votes.up"},{$size:"$votes.down"}]}}
    },
    {
        $sort:{numVotes:-1}
    },
    {
        $match:{
            timestamp:{
                '$lte':new Date(),
                '$gte':new Date(ISODate().getTime()-7*1000*86400)}
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to match at the end of your pipeline, which supposes you have projected timestamp field, and you haven't done that.

I believe what you want is to filter data before aggregation, so you should place match at the top of your aggregation array.

Try this:

```
db.articles.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        timestamp: {
            '$lte': new Date(),
            '$gte': new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 7 * 1000 * 86400)
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        _id: 1,
        numVotes: {
            $subtract: [{
                $size: "$votes.up"
            }, {
                $size: "$votes.down"
            }]
        }
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
        numVotes: -1
    }
}])
```

Comment: Awesome! I thought the order didn't matter.

Comment: This is why they call it a "Pipeline". You need to think aggregation as a sequence of transformations which will take place in order. You can even project and match data more than once. For example: you could match, project, group, project again, match, and finally sort.